# Counting distinct values while comparing another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table, office365

I've been given the task of getting a housing count (from about 20k addresses). We have a spreadsheet with names, addresses and a "zone" number, but have to filter out the duplicates. Here's some sample data:

```
Zone    Address
1   302 DIGITAL DR 
1   309 DIGITAL DR 
1   309 DIGITAL DR 
1   310 DIGITAL DR 
1   311 DIGITAL DR 
1   314 DIGITAL DR 
1   315 DIGITAL DR 
1   319 DIGITAL DR 
1   320 DIGITAL DR 
2   325 DIGITAL DR 
2   329 DIGITAL DR 
2   333 DIGITAL DR 
2   333 DIGITAL DR 
2   334 DIGITAL DR 
2   334 DIGITAL DR 
2   338 DIGITAL DR 
2   339 DIGITAL DR 
2   339 DIGITAL DR 
2   342 DIGITAL DR
```

My task is to count up the number of unique addresses in each zone (you'll see a few duplicates in this sample). Expected results for this would be `8` for Zone 1 and `7` for Zone 2.

I'm sure there's a super-fancy Excel formula that can do this for me. Maybe even in a table of its own?

```
Zone    Count
1       8
2       7
```

Anyone clever enough to be able to help out?

Comment: I've got Office 365... so 2013 I guess is the most recent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure Office 365 has [Distinct Count](http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/distinct-count-in-pivot-tables-finally-in-excel-2013/) but an alternative is to copy your data (if to be cautious), apply Remove Duplicates and pivot what is left with `Zone` for ROWS, and Count of Zone for VALUES.

Comment: Just saw this.  You can also use the Advanced Filter to do the copy; and select Unique Records only; then create the Pivot

Comment: Got so stuck in thinking it needed to be done with a formula, that I never thought of a pivot table.